# Xcode 7.3 Command fail due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, segmentation-fault, swift2, xcode7.3

I'm working on a remote project and when I updated it I found this error. I was making a research about this and many says it caused by 3rd party frameworks. So I checked the log about the error and I guess Firebase is causing it (according to the view controller referenced in the error description). So what can I do?

[image: Log about the error]

P.S. I'm using Swift 2.2 on Xcode 7.3.2. I also used a previous version of Xcode (7.3).

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods (looks like it since I see the `-DCOCOAPODS=1` linker flag)? I recently upgraded to CocoaPods 1.0 and the segfault went away.

Comment: Yes I'm using cocoaPods. I'll try to upgrade and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah I solved this issue by upgrading CocoaPods. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Solved by upgrading to CocoaPods 1.0

Comment: Yeah, that's the solution. Thanks!